# EXC_BAD_ACCESS with NSXMLParser

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsxmlparser, exc-bad-access

I'm getting EXC_BAD_ACCESS while parsing XML file in my Xcode4 iPhone app

Although I read many similar errors questions here but couldn't figure out how to fix my code!

It crashed at the [parser parse]

Then I enabled NSZombieEnabled and got the following error:

```
*** -[CFString appendString:]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x588c3a0
```

The following is my code related to the parsing section:

```
-(void)openXML {
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://localhost/news.xml"];    
    NSURLRequest *req = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    NSURLConnection *con = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:req delegate:self];
    [con release];
}

-(void)parseXMLData:(NSData *)xmlData{
    parser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithData:xmlData];
    parser.delegate = self;
    [parser parse];
}

-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response{    
    xmlDocument = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
}

-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data{
    [xmlDocument appendData:data];
}

-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection{
    [self parseXMLData:xmlDocument];
}

- (void)parserDidStartDocument:(NSXMLParser *)parser{
    [offersData removeAllObjects];
}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict{
    completeString = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName{
    [offersData addObject:completeString];
    [completeString release];
}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string{
    [completeString appendString:string];
}

- (void)parserDidEndDocument:(NSXMLParser *)parser{
    [offersTableView reloadData];
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The message means the code is trying to call a method on a string object (meaning it's not nil) but the object has been deallocated (released).

In `didEndElement`, you are releasing `completeString` but not setting it to `nil`.  This makes the error you're getting possible.

What's probably happening is after `didEndElement`, `foundCharacters` is getting called *before* a `didStartElement` (maybe there's some whitespace like a new line between tags) so the `completeString` is still deallocated resulting in a crash.

After doing `[completeString release];` also set it to `nil` so any method calls that might be done on it before it gets re-allocated will not crash.

It would also then be a good idea to only do the `addObject` if completeString is not `nil` (which could happen depending on how the xml tags are nested).

So try changing `didEndElement` to:

```
if (completeString != nil) {
    [offersData addObject:completeString];
}
[completeString release];
completeString = nil;
```

Comment: Its working now, but only if the XML has 1 element with its children, if I add 1 more element its not parsing :/

Comment: Please post a small sample of the xml that causes a problem and explain in more detail how it's not working (if crash what's the error and what line, etc).

Comment: I found the problem but couldn't know why! There was "&" symbol in one of the element that caused this problem, as soon as I removed I got all the XML data correctly!

Comment: The xml was bad if it had a raw "&".  That symbol has to be escaped as `&amp;` to be valid xml.  There are four other special characters.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1091945/where-can-i-get-a-list-of-the-xml-document-escape-characters.

Answer (score 0):

if u synthesized completeString then u have to call with self with dot to retain

change this

```
  completeString = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
```

to

```
 self.completeString = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
```